# Should a useful gem release have version 1.0?

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems

Found this related post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139/should-a-first-release-be-an-0-1-version-or-1-0b, but it is not about Ruby Gems. I am asking about the best and common practice for Ruby Gems.

I'll start with 0.0.1, and probably get to 0.0.10 when it is fully tested and ready for use.

Does it make sense to leave the version at 0.x.x? Or does that mean that the gem is beta and not stable and not ready for use? Is it better to set the version to 1.0.0?

Hosting on RubyGems and GitHub.

Comment: Have a look at http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#semantic-versioning and http://semver.org/

Comment: Thanks, the second link answered the question from a documentation perspective. Is that what people really do for Ruby Gems?

Comment: Yes. People generally specify dependencies as e.g. `~> 1.4`, expecting that they can update to anything else in the 1.x series without breaking anything. Semantic versioning will make everyone happy. A key point for your scenario: "Version 1.0.0 defines the public API." Release 1.0 when you're ready to handle any breaking changes with another major version bump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to matt, the docs at [semver.org](http://semver.org/) say that yes, release software should be at least v1.0.